# Group policy preferences that only target 32bit or 64bit os

Tags: group-policy

I am currently deploying some files through GPP to a folder under program files. I now have to differ between a 64bits and 32bits os. What is the easy way to filter out what computer to target with the targeting editor?

1. Wmi: SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE AddressWidth = 32
2. environment: programfilesx86
3. registry: ???
4. os selection in the targeting editor

I am currently looking at using a WMI select, but it seems a but it seems overkill. What method is the best?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The WMI Filter method is the best one to use because it's defined seperately of the GPO, natively administered in the GPMC, and can be linked to one or more GPOs as required.

Target 32-bit OS's with:

- Namespace: root\CIMv2
- Query: Select * from Win32_Processor where AddressWidth = '32'

Target 64-bit OS's with:

- Namespace: root\CIMv2
- Query: Select * from Win32_Processor where AddressWidth = '64'

Answer (score 19):

In my experience if there is an issue with WMI on the system it can not run the query. If you are using Windows 2008 preferences then I would use a environment variable for the Group Policy item-level targeting filter.

For x64
the environment variable `%Processor_Architecture%` is `AMD64`

For x86
the environment variable `%Processor_Architecture%` is `x86`

Environment variables are much more stable than WMI

Comment: I use this a lot.  It works better than WMI in my experience.

Comment: The performance impact is the bigger determining factor in my opinion. Both solutions work, however, this method will result in significantly faster execution. WMI is great and is a invaluable tool in every admins toolbox, however, it is extremely slow in most instances and should be avoided whenever possible.