# WMI Processor Filtering Preventing GPO Software Installation?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I've been battling this issue for a few days.  I've been trying to deploy Symantec Endpoint Protection for a few days.  I created a GPO and linked it to a WMI Filter so that it would only target the 64 bit desktops.  When I check with Group Policy Modeling, it appears that it will work with this WMI filter.  However, it only ever installs once I remove the WMI filter.  Any idea why this would be happening?

This is the WMI Filter:

> **Namespace:** root\CIMv2 
>   **Query:** Select AddressWidth from Win32_Processor where (AddressWidth=”64″)

Comment: Not for nothing but you know you can "push" install the client from the SEPM console, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah, I know.  I'm just trying to do it this way so it'll automatically install on new workstations.

Comment: I have no idea why that wouldn't work, but you might try OSArchitecture and see if that will work.  http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1432-using-wmi-filters-to-apply-group-policy-to-a-target-operating-system

Comment: You also might use an environment variable filter per the 2nd answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/18670/group-policy-preferences-that-only-target-32bit-or-64bit-os

Comment: Filter only targets 64bit, maybe your Symantec Endpoint Protection is 32bit

Comment: @user288258 Nah, it's the 64 bit client I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Your WMI query has invalid quote characters.

```
Select AddressWidth from Win32_Processor where (AddressWidth=”64″)
```

Should be:

```
Select AddressWidth from Win32_Processor where (AddressWidth="64")
```

Or:

```
Select AddressWidth from Win32_Processor where (AddressWidth='64')
```

Comment: None of those above worked for me, but     'Select AddressWidth from Win32_Processor where (AddressWidth=64)'     seems to work for me. That only makes me more confused.

Comment: The weird thing is that in GPO modeling the filter I was using was evaluating to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I am Chetan Savade from Symantec Technical Support Team.

Just in case looking for Symantec best practice articles, here are they:

Creating a GPO software distribution
http://www.symantec.com/docs/HOWTO81180

Installing Windows client software using third-party tools
http://www.symantec.com/docs/HOWTO81045

Best Regards,
Chetan